# What is the simplest way to implement fuzzy relational composition of two matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix, relation, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

What is the simplest way to implement fuzzy relational composition of two matrices in R? I coded a version of it but it's supposedly very slow, so I wonder if there's vectorized operations that can make it faster

```
circ_prod <- function(R,S) {
  if(ncol(R) != nrow(S)) errorCondition("dimensions don't match")
  R_circ_S <- matrix(0, nrow(R), ncol(S))
  for (i in 1:nrow(R)) {
    for (k in 1:ncol(S))
     R_circ_S[i,k] <- max(pmin(R[i,],S[,k]))
  }
  R_circ_S
}
```

There is a link that explains why doing so is important [what is fuzzy relational composition](https://codecrucks.com/fuzzy-composition-max-min-and-max-product/) and some small examples.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but we need to see sample input, expected output, and some kind of explanation of how to get from one to the other.

Comment: Should be in the link @MikaelJagan

Comment: Hi @monotonic. This is not a good question for SO in its current form. SO is about *specific* code issues, that can be demonstrated & verified with sample data and some attempt at translating the problem into code. At the moment your question either reads like you're asking somebody else to do a project for you, or you're asking for a package /tool which is OT here on SO. I suggest editing your post addressing Mikael Jagan's suggestions and then flag the post for "Reopen".

Comment: Consider that, if your link breaks, then any answers will be entirely without context for someone who comes across this question in the future.

Comment: @MikaelJagan that's a good point and thanks for mentioning that. I just coded a for loop version, and thanks for providing the answer. Can we reopen this questions so others may see it too?

Comment: @MauritsEvers good to reopen?

Comment: @monotonic Flagged for reopen. Needs one more vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some more options. `maxmin1` and `maxmin2` implement the max-min composition. `maxprod1` and `maxprod2` implement the max-product composition.

`maxmin1` and `maxprod1` are going to perform similarly to (if not worse than) a nested `for` loop, since `apply` has a loop in its body.

`maxmin2` and `maxprod2` are optimized versions that rely solely on vectorized functions. When `ncol(R)` exceeds 2, they use `colMaxs` from package `matrixStats` to find columnwise maxima efficiently.

Implementing these functions in C would allow you optimize further.

```r
maxmin1 <- function(R, S) {
    t(apply(R, 1L, function(x) apply(pmin(S, x), 2L, max)))
}
maxmin2 <- function(R, S) {
    m <- (d <- dim(R))[1L]
    p <- d[2L]
    n <- dim(S)[2L]
    if (p == 1L) {
        return(matrix(pmin.int(rep(R, each = n), S), m, n, byrow = TRUE))
    }
    r <- sequence.default(nvec = rep.int(p, m * n), from = rep(seq_len(m), each = n), by = m)  
    x <- pmin.int(S, R[r])
    if (p == 2L) {
        y <- x[seq.int(1L, length(x), 2L) + (x[c(TRUE, FALSE)] < x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])]
    } else {
        y <- matrixStats::colMaxs(matrix(x, p))
    }
    matrix(y, m, byrow = TRUE)
}

maxprod1 <- function(R, S) {
    t(apply(R, 1L, function(x) apply(S * x, 2L, max)))
}
maxprod2 <- function(R, S) {
    m <- (d <- dim(R))[1L]
    p <- d[2L]
    n <- dim(S)[2L]
    if (p == 1L) {
        return(matrix(rep(R, each = n) * S, m, n, byrow = TRUE))
    }
    r <- sequence.default(nvec = rep.int(p, m * n), from = rep(seq_len(m), each = n), by = m)  
    x <- as.double(S) * R[r]
    if (p == 2L) {
        y <- x[seq.int(1L, length(x), 2L) + (x[c(TRUE, FALSE)] < x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])]
    } else {
        y <- matrixStats::colMaxs(matrix(x, p))
    }
    matrix(y, m, byrow = TRUE)
}
```

```r
R <- matrix(c(0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3), 2L, 2L)
R
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]  0.7  0.6
## [2,]  0.8  0.3

S <- matrix(c(0.8, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7), 2L, 3L)
S
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  0.8  0.5  0.4
## [2,]  0.1  0.6  0.7

maxmin1(R, S)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  0.7  0.6  0.6
## [2,]  0.8  0.5  0.4

maxmin2(R, S)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]  0.7  0.6  0.6
## [2,]  0.8  0.5  0.4

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(maxmin1(R, S), maxmin2(R, S), times = 10000L)
## Unit: microseconds
##           expr    min     lq      mean median     uq      max neval
##  maxmin1(R, S) 34.645 36.244 40.519689 36.695 37.884 3165.159 10000
##  maxmin2(R, S)  3.198  3.567  4.236501  3.813  4.018 1030.412 10000

maxprod1(R, S)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 0.56 0.36 0.42
## [2,] 0.64 0.40 0.32

maxprod2(R, S)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 0.56 0.36 0.42
## [2,] 0.64 0.40 0.32

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(maxprod1(R, S), maxprod2(R, S), times = 10000L)
## Unit: microseconds
##            expr    min     lq      mean median     uq      max neval
##  maxprod1(R, S) 25.543 26.814 29.412076 27.265 28.003 1174.527 10000
##  maxprod2(R, S)  2.911  3.239  3.723411  3.403  3.608  932.586 10000
```

Comment: I'd give this +2 if I could. This is an excellent answer!